# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smallint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server, this question might be repeated here. Since i haven't find a solution for my problem. I wished to post here. So here is my problem

```
select(volume * speed)  from traffic_data_replica;
```

I am trying to multiply values from two columns , data type is smallint for both columns. Error i got is :

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smallint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast one of the values to a "bigger" type before the calculation:

```
select cast(volume as int) * speed
from traffic_data_replica;
```

You can also do this easily by multiplying by 1.0:

```
select 1.0*volume*speed
from  traffic_data_replica
```

Comment: This was really a good information :)  @Gordon Linoff  Really thankful to you . "Information is wealth"